# How do I decrypt ecryptfs files?

Tags: ecryptfs

I tried to setup ecryptfs on Debian Jessie, but I made an error and I cannot login now. So I took my encrypted files, and placed them in a safe place. How do I decrypt these files? I still remember the password.

I've searched on every page on google, but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty simple. If you have ecryptfs installed you can simply use the command

```
ecryptfs-recover-private
```

This will find the location of your encrypted files and will mount them decrypted in a temporary location.

Type:

```
man ecryptfs-recover-private
```

for more information.

Comment: It says "ERROR: No private directories found; make sure that your root filesystem is mounted."

Comment: You sad, that you placed your encrypted home in a safe location. Where is that location? What files did you copy to that location?

Comment: The files are on my usb, I copied a file called "Info.txt" with all my information. I also have a .asc file on it with my gpg key.

Comment: Did you copy the files in "/home/.ecryptfs"? This is the location where the Encrypted files are stored.

Comment: No I just added the text file to my usb, that is all I have and my password.

Comment: Sorry but then it is impossible to recover your files. The encrypted files are located at /home/.ecryptfs. If you lost these files there is obviously no chance to get your files back.

Comment: So what would be the point in backupping those files if its not even help me recover? Is there some way I can restore the deleted files to do this?

Comment: I just tried to recover the .ecryptfs folder, but it has never existed, what does this mean?

Comment: The files are usually located in `~/.Private`, not in `~/.ecryptfs` (but the latter stores the key information and is also important, unless you noted down the 32 character hex passphrase, the `wrapped_passphrase` file).